# Load application.conf from folder in deployed Scala app

Tags: scala, gradle, typesafe-config

I have an application that loads configuration from application.conf using ConfigFactory: lazy val myConfig = ConfigFactory.load(pathToConfig)
The application.conf is initially located in src/main/resources

When I deploy my application I want it to load the config from APP_HOME/conf/application.conf

To do so, I excluded the application.conf from the resource folder when building the Rmp and I have added my APP_HOME/conf to the class path.

```
jar {
   exclude '*.conf'
}
```

and

```
startScripts {
   classpath += files('src/main/resources')
   doLast {
       def windowsScriptFile = file getWindowsScript()
       def unixScriptFile    = file getUnixScript()
       println('unix script is ' + unixScriptFile.text)
       windowsScriptFile.text = windowsScriptFile.text.replace('%APP_HOME%\\lib\\resources', '%APP_HOME%\\conf')
       unixScriptFile.text  = unixScriptFile.text.replace('\$APP_HOME/lib/resources', '\$APP_HOME/conf')
       println('after unix script is ' + unixScriptFile.text)
   }
}
```

The odd thing is that when I modify the $APP_HOME/conf/application.conf and restart the app, the changes are not picked up: ie the old configuration is still being used

Any idea what might cause this or how I can print where the config is being loaded from would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

With many attempts, I got it to work by calling lazy val myConfig = ConfigFactory.load() without specifying the conf file name or path.

Although it solved my issue I still don't understand why calling load with the file name or file path didn't work